# Will glasses make me look more professional?

Tags: interviewing, appearance, grooming

This may come off as vanity, but like many aspects of personal grooming, it's the small things that add a lot both in terms of reception and perception. And I've found that being perceived as smart or professional or hardworking is much more important than any of those things.

I don't *need* glasses, as far as I'm aware I have perfect eyes. But I'm considering purchasing some to appear more professional. I automatically assume that a person wearing glasses is smarter than a person without.

Will I look smarter or more professional in glasses?

And will it affect my chances of getting hired/promoted?

---

**Edit:** The type of glasses I'm thinking have anti-glare lens coating. They're not lens-less or useless, they just aren't required for seeing.

Comment: No.  It will make you look like you are wearing glasses.

Comment: If ever anybody finds out, you will become a legend.

Comment: The sunglasses and headphones in your picture make you look intelligent.  I would just stay with that look.

Comment: This sounds right up your alley...http://www.realmenrealstyle.com/glasses-perception-intelligence/. Let me know what you think.

Comment: You've somewhat answered your own question - yes you would look smarter or more professional to some people (who have the same preconceptions as you) but not to everyone. It's highly opinion-based.

Comment: You should use contact len to change your eyes color too, you would look like a chameleon..  but seriously in any case if someone happen to know you fake, you better be ready for the backlash

Answer (score 3):

Off-hand, I would say no.  You wouldn't be wearing the glasses to "look smarter or more professional", **you'd be wearing them to complete the costume/uniform of what you see as "professional".**

However, *if* accessorizing in this manner gives the feeling that you now look the part for you're trying to play, and **indirectly** you behave more professionally by being more assured and less fidgety, go for it.

Comment: I don't see "completing the costume" as being a bad thing. In my office we have a dress code, which I exceed for the purpose of professionalism. I don't see the difference between wearing a dress shirt rather than a polo or glasses rather than nothing.

Comment: @Coomie Not aware of any dress code which requires glasses. Normally, you use glasses to help you see. For example I need them to read something far away, but when I'm working at my desk it is usually more comfortable to take off.